# Changing the language of Windows 10 store

Tags: windows-10

For some reason my apps and store is on my local language while windows itself is on English. How can I change everything to be on English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the Local Language from the Region and Language settings in Control Panel

Answer (score 21):

Go to *Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Language* and either remove the unnecessary language **OR** if you need to keep the language for some reason (e.g. keyboard input in your local language), move it below English using the "Move down" button (shown below). The store uses the language that's at the top of the list.

> [image]

---

Alternatively, open the Settings app, go to the *Time & language* category, then click the *Region & language* sidebar item. Here you'll se a list of installed languages. Click the language you want to use and press *Set as default*

[image]

Comment: I had to select the language on the country or region selection from above and it worked.

Comment: I had English (Europe) at the top and it didn't work. I switched to English (United States) and it works. Seems like European version of English is not supported by MS Store.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers were probably correct, however languages have now, in June 2020, been migrated to Settings from Control Panel. (The confusion between settings and control panel drives me mad. Why not just have one or the other, but not both!?)

So the answer should now be

```
Press Windows key -> Search for "Settings" -> Search for "Language" in settings
Change order of languages, bringing your preferred language to the top.
```

In my case, the Microsoft Store App started appearing in English when I moved English above Italian (I'm English but live in Italy), as below

[image]

Comment: Win10 is keeping changing its settings  all the time :( Hate it! In the old time, I can blindly locate every settings of XP. And, the language settings is a total DIZASTER!  They have no experience in multi-language working. Have you ever typing and switching between  English, Japanese and Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store seems to respect the "Country or region" setting for determining the language so if you have Switzerland there you get the Windows Store in German.

I had to switch to United Kingdom to get English even though my Windows Language is English.

[image]